# Resubmitting/scheduling task from the task itself - is it a good practice?

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor, scheduledexecutorservice

Consider we have a scheduled executor service:

```
ScheduledExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(...);
```

And for some logic we want to retry a task execution. The following approach seems to be smelling for me, but I can't understand why:

```
threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ...
        if (needToBeScheduled()) {
           threadPool.schedule(this, delay, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } else if (needToBeResubmitted()) {
           threadPool.submit(this);
        }
    }
});
```

The one obvious problem I see is that this code is not possible to convert to lambda:

```
threadPool.submit(()-> {
    // ...
    if (needToBeScheduled()) {
        threadPool.schedule(this, delay, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } else if (needToBeResubmitted()) {
        threadPool.submit(this);
    }
});
```

^^ this won't compile, as we can not refer `this` from lambda. Though it can be solved by introducing a method which produces such an instance and provide it instead of `this`.

But this is only one disadvantage I see. Is anything else here which can cause any problems? Perhaps there is a more proper approach? Move this logic to `ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute()` (this causes type conversion though...)?

Assuming that object is stateless, i.e. there are no object variables in `Runnable` instance.

**P.S.** The logic of what to do (reschedule task or resubmit or do nothing) is based on some information retrieved from the database (or any external source). So `Runnable` is still stateless, but it calculates the outcome based on some results of its work.

Comment: I do agree that it seems to smell... I think I would use an external handler for such cases but I also don't think there is something inherently wrong doing it the way you do. At least I don't see why it should not work, let us say it like that.

Comment: Agree with @Ben, there is nothing wrong. That is how we used to reinstall signal handlers in Unix :)

Comment: It's fine. The smell is (I guess) because you want to separate the retry logic from the actual stuff your task does - do that and it won't smell anymore :)

Comment: can you change the `stateless` part about that `Runnable`? It's interesting that I have put close to this into our production... this runnable is "killed/ignored", but it creates a new one with the previous meta-data and adds +1 to the retry count...

Comment: @Eugene I'm sorry, but I don't get what do you mean I should change in this part. Could you please clarify it in more details.

Comment: you said it's stateless, so my real question is how do you know how many times to retry actually?

Comment: It depends on its internal logic. It reads something from the Database and then decides what to do. Do you want me to add this part into the question description?

Comment: @Andremoniy plz do, yes. also don't forget to tag me next time ;)

Comment: but either way - this is fine with me, dropping the current runnable and getting a new one, at least this is what I did in our production (I hope it makes sense)

Comment: @Eugene I've updated my question as you asked. And yes, it makes sense what you said about getting a new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I don't like the approach where a task (a simple independent unit of work) decides whether it should put itself in the service or not and interacts with the `ExecutorService` directly. I believe `// ...` is the only part a task should execute.

I would convert a `Runnable` in a `Callable<Boolean>`:

```
Callable<Boolean> task = () -> {
    // ...
    return needToBeScheduled; // or sth more complex with several boolean fields
};
```

And I would definitely move that logic outside a task (for example, into a service method):

```
Future<Boolean> future = threadPool.submit(task);

try {
    boolean needToBeScheduled = future.get();

    if (needToBeScheduled) {
        threadPool.schedule(task, delay, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

By something more complex I meant a class that comprises 2 `boolean` fields. It takes `Supplier<Boolean>`s to make things lazy.

```
final class TaskResult {
    private final Supplier<Boolean> needToBeScheduled;
    private final Supplier<Boolean> needToBeResubmitted;

    private TaskResult(Supplier<Boolean> needToBeScheduled, Supplier<Boolean> needToBeResubmitted) {
        this.needToBeScheduled = needToBeScheduled;
        this.needToBeResubmitted = needToBeResubmitted;
    }

    public static TaskResult of(Supplier<Boolean> needToBeScheduled, Supplier<Boolean> needToBeResubmitted) {
        return new TaskResult(needToBeScheduled, needToBeResubmitted);
    }

    public boolean needToBeScheduled() {
        return needToBeScheduled != null && needToBeScheduled.get();
    }

    public boolean needToBeResubmitted() {
        return needToBeResubmitted != null && needToBeResubmitted.get();
    }
}
```

With a few changes to the above example, we have:

```
Callable<TaskResult> task = () -> {
    // ...
    return TaskResult.of(() -> needToBeScheduled(), () -> needToBeResubmitted());
};

final Future<TaskResult> future = threadPool.submit(task);

try {
    final TaskResult result = future.get();

    if (result.needToBeScheduled()) {
        threadPool.schedule(task, delay, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    if (result.needToBeResubmitted()) {
        threadPool.submit(task);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `final TaskResult result = future.get();`: your task submitter thread waits for the task to complete

Comment: I like your idea with `Callable<T>` interface, though I would it rather using some enum type as a result.

Comment: @giorgiga, yes, I think the results of resubmitting/rescheduling are being calculated after a task has done its main work.

Comment: @Andremoniy, yes, it might be a better option